# Can we use derived class in place for anywhere requiring the base class? (In the context of templates)

Tags: c++, templates, derived-class

I'm am quite new to C++ but I could not seem to find an answer to this question.

If I have a class template `<Type>` with a constructor taking in object type of `ClassA<Type>`, and I have another class derived in the following manner:
`class ClassB : public ClassA<Animal>`, am I able to pass in an object of type `classB` into the first constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends entirely whether the constructor takes its argument by reference/pointer.  If it does not, the object will be [sliced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/501250) into a `ClassA<Type>`.

```
#include <memory>

template <typename Type>
class ClassA {};

class ClassB : public ClassA<Animal> {};

template <typename Type>
class ClassUser1 {
public:
    explicit ClassUser1(ClassA<Type>);
}

template <typename Type>
class ClassUser2 {
public:
    explicit ClassUser2(std::unique_ptr<ClassA<Type>>);
}
```

In this setup, calling `ClassUser1<Animal>::ClassUser1{ClassB{}}` will construct a temporary `ClassB`, which will be used to move-construct a `ClassA<Animal>` (slicing the object).

Calling `ClassUser2<Animal>::ClassUser2{std::make_unique<ClassB>()}` will work as you would expect; the pointed-to instance remains a `ClassB`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is first time I heard of slicing. I would assume if the constructor takes in the argument by reference, then I am able to pass in the derived class object into them. However, I get the following error when compiling/building:
 `note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::list<std::shared_ptr<const ClassB> >'  to 'list<std::shared_ptr<const ClassA<Animal > > &'`, which somehow indicates the derived classes cannot be implicitly converted by the compiler to the base class?

Comment: Just to clarify, notice in the example I posted here, I'm passing in a list of such class objects, instead of just a single object (The constructor expects a list of class objects). But I suppose the example still holds?

Comment: @czl Unfortunately, you can't do this because template arguments cannot be contravariant. In the example I gave, the `unique_ptr<ClassB>` is used to move-construct a `unique_ptr<ClassA<Type>>`. Because these pointers are nested in a list, this isn't directly possible. You would need to copy the list, or you need to make the constructor a template that can take `std::list<std::shared_ptr<T>>` (or more simply `T`) and it could `static_assert` on the type of `T`, or simply proceed as though `T` is an acceptable type and fail to instantiate otherwise.

Comment: Template instantiations A<X> and A<Y> are distinct and unrelated types, even if the underlying arguments X and Y are convertible to each other.  Thus, a list of X cannot be converted to a list of Y because the two types, though "lists", are uniquely unrelated types.
One must explicitly write code to permit conversions between them, like for any types.  (For example, a templated operator=, constructor, or other function.)  Stdlib classes (like list<T>)  cannot be changed like that, however.

Comment: @czl One fairly straightforward option would be to have the constructor be a template that takes a pair of iterators (`template <typename Iterator> ClassName(Iterator begin, Iterator end);`) instead of a list. Then you could use this constructor with other container types, and you _can_ have the `shared_ptr`s be contravariant.

Comment: Thanks guys! I totally realised a list of type ClassB cannot be treated as a list of type ClassA even if ClassB is derived from ClassA. What I probably can do is either to a single list transformation, or just initialise a list of ClassA right from the beginning and insert ClassB objects directly into them (please correct them if I am wrong).